# Perl seek or read and discard results

Tags: perl, io

I am reading an opened filehandle as follows:

```
open(my $fh, "-|", "zcat test.csv.gz") or die "Cannot open test.csv.gz:  $!";

read $fh, ???, 256;
print ">>", readline($fh), "<<\n";

close $fh;
```

Now, I want to seek to a known position, 256 bytes in this case.

I can't seek, because this is a filehandle based on another program's STDOUT.  I tried that and the seek() does nothing.  I can read and discard the data, but when seeking into a large result, this will waste memory loading and discarding it.

What can I put in for ???? that acts like /dev/null?  Or is there another approach?

Comment: Re "*I tried that and the seek() does nothing.*", Well, it returns error `ESPIPE`

Answer (score 3):

For 256 bytes, this is surely a micro-optimization. For larger seeks like 256MB, find an amount of memory you are willing to (temporarily) sacrifice and perform multiple reads.

```
use List::Util qw( min );

# Making $BUFFER_SIZE a multiple of 16 KiB covers makes sure the read is efficient.
my $BUFFER_SIZE = 65_536;
my $n = 256_000_000;

my $buffer = "";
while ($n) {
    my $bytes_read = sysread($fh, $buffer, min($BUFFER_SIZE, $n));
    die($!) if !defined($bytes_read);
    die("Premature EOF") if !$bytes_read;

    $n -= $bytes_read;
}

# Doesn't necessarily return memory back to the OS,
# but it does makes it available for Perl.
undef $buffer;
```

Comment: Fixed some issues: 1) `read` (and `sysread`) can return less than the amount requested, especially when reading from something other than a plain file. 2) `sysread` is more efficient than `read` since it's a single system call with far less overhead. `sysread` doesn't support PerlIO layers (e.g. `:encoding`), so switch back to `read` if you use those. 3) The IO buffer size was switched to 8 KiB some time ago now. Of course, with `sysread`, that wouldn't matter.

Comment: Ok, so one must use a while loop with a good size buffer and repeatedly read.  Yes, I am really trying to seek close to the end of multi-gigabyte files, and 256 was just for illustration.  This seems to work well.